# Регистрация SSL сертификата на порт Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, .net-core

Я имею .NET Core ConsoleApp, где запущен HTTPListener, он слушает 443 порт моего сервера, но у меня есть трудность с установкой SSL сертификата на порт. У меня получалось сделать это в windows, при помощи такой команды:
**netsh http add sslcert ipport:0.0.0.0:443 certhash=5d48e604007b867ae8a69260a4ad318d2c05d8ff appid={EDE3C891-306C-40fe-BAD4-895B236A1CC8}**, и все работает очень хорошо
Сейчас же я имею VPS Ubuntu и хочу провернуть тот же трюк, но не могу найти информацию. Пробовал установить сертификат на nginx по совету из интернета, но в таком случае мое .NET Core ConsoleApp не может слушать порт, так как он занят
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Пусть ConsoleApp слушает какой-нибудь другой порт, а nginx будет перенаправлять в него запросы (proxy_pass)

Comment: К сожалению, в таком случае связь между nginx и .net console идет по HTTP протоколу. А я хотел бы, чтобы весь трафик шифровался

Comment: Зачем шифровать локальный трафик? Кто его может перехватить?